# Export C# to word with template

Tags: c#

so I have a word template like the one below'

[word template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU81h.png)

I changed all fields to data from datatable but I have several values and only one value is changed

```
for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex < dt.Rows.Count; rowindex++)
            {

                int first = 1;
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<d>", first);
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<barang>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["nama_produk"].ToString());
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<var>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["nama_varian"].ToString());
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<size>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["size"].ToString());
                this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<jml>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["jml_pembelian"].ToString());
                first = first + 1;



            }
```

Below are the values in the database and i have more than 1 result i want to replace all in template with all result in database.

[database result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovcsd.png)

below is the result of the above process

[result findandreplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB9fH.png)

The question is how to find and replace the field with data table array. i just replace field with 1 result data, i want replace field with 3 data from the result.

Comment: Whats the question or the issue?

Comment: The question is how to find and replace the field with data table array. i just replace field with 1 result data, i want replace field with 3 data from the result.

Comment: You need to provide info regarding the "this" variable. During each iteration, you are replacing the values of your template first time and afterwards its not found. You need to create a list or something to use for each iteration. Think about it, after first iteration, there is no longer <d> or <barang> to replace as its replaced in first iteration

Comment: I have changed 1 data from the database, but what I want is all data from database to word, not just one

Comment: can i use bookmarks for that kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with overwriting the original template in the first iteration and in other iterations in your loop, that template no longer is valid for your work. Try something like this,

```
List<string> allWords = new List<string>();
int first = 1;

for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex < dt.Rows.Count; rowindex++)
{
    string newWordApp = wordApp; // assuming wordApp is a string.
    this.FindAndReplace(newWordApp, "<d>", first);
    this.FindAndReplace(newWordApp, "<barang>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["nama_produk"].ToString());
    this.FindAndReplace(newWordApp, "<var>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["nama_varian"].ToString());
    this.FindAndReplace(newWordApp, "<size>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["size"].ToString());
    this.FindAndReplace(newWordApp, "<jml>", dt.Rows[rowindex]["jml_pembelian"].ToString());
    first = first + 1;
    allWords.Add(newWordApp);
}
```

This way your template (wordApp) does not get updated and you get a list of all words from your database rows replaced in `allWords`.

**Also**, you need to bring your variable `first` initialized **outside** of your loop. otherwise, it will ALWAYS be one.

Comment: I try your solution but still, the result is just one data.

Comment: How do you check if it is only one data? What you doing with `allWords` variable from above solution? @Haryo